# MongoDB: Updating the path 'Y' would create a conflict at 'Y'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query being executed:

```
const myData = await this.findOneAndUpdate({
  myId,
  color,
}, {
  $setOnInsert: {
    myId,
    color,
    date: now.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    counter: myObj.counter - amount,
  },
  $inc: {
    counter: -amount
  },
}, {
  new: true,
  upsert: true,
});
```

I get the error:

```
"Updating the path 'count' would create a conflict at 'count'"
```

First I thought the error was happening because of the version of `mongoose`, but I don't think that is the case.
Now I understand this is happening because I have `color` **in both $setOnInsert** and **$inc**, but I don't understand why.

Also: This code works on `MongoDB 3.4.24 Community` but does NOT WORK on `MongoDB 5.0.11 Community`

So my questions are:

- why this error is happening exactly? Could this be a [BUG](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7003)?
- Why this works in older version of MongoDB?
- What would be the best approach to refactor this?

Comment: Whether this is a bug in mongoose or MongoDB itself, you can simply check by yourself. Run the same command in mongo shell `mongosh` BTW, you should **never** store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the above error from MongoDB, because of the way `$inc` works, with `upsert: true`, `new: true`, `$inc` will insert a new document. Check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3hep96oz4G0).

In your case, you have `$setOnInsert` and `$inc`, in case your matching document is not found, both the operators will try to set the value of key `counter`, which will create a conflict, hence you see the error. To fix it, you can use the pipeline form of updates, something like this:

```
const myData = await this.findOneAndUpdate({
  myId,
  color,
}, [
   {
     $set: {
        myId,
        color,
        date: {
           $cond: {
             if: {$eq: ["$$ROOT", null]},
             then: now.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
             else: "$$ROOT.date"
           }
        },
        counter: {
           $cond: {
             if: {$eq: ["$$ROOT", null]},
             then: myObj.counter - amount,
             else: {$substract: ["$$ROOT.counter", amount]}
           }
        }
     }
   }
], {
  new: true,
  upsert: true,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunatelly I'm receiving `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$set' in '0.$set' is not valid for storage` when using `MongoDB V3.4`. I'll be able to use this soon, because we will upgrade to V4.4.  WOuld be there an approach compatible with V3.4?

Comment: I am afraid not. You will have to fetch the document first, query and then upsert it using another query for version 3.4